# Where does Apalon's Pimp Your Screen mac app does saves downladed images?

Tags: mac, applications, data-transfer, folders

I've just installed [Pimp your screen Apalon's Mac app](http://www.apalon.com/pimp_your_screen_mac.html) and downloaded a bunch of images, where are images stored on my system after download?

I've searched in the application contents in my \Applications folder and my iPhoto pictures.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Probably because you did not provide any details at all about what you have tried to do to find the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you clicked "Save" and applied the wallpaper to your desktop, open "System Preferences" and navigate into "Desktop & Screen Saver". See your current wallpaper in the  top left corner? Hold down your mouse at that picture and drag to some folder, then you get the file.

Comment: Also I found the directory where Pimp Your Screen stores the wallpaper(no 's') is "~/Library/Containers/com.apalon.pimpyourscreenmac/Data/Library/Application Support/Pimp Your Screen/Desktop/" However, as I noted there, the app only stores ONE wallpaper there. As soon as you save another wallpaper, the previous one will be deleted. Also note that the exact directory may vary among different versions. The method I said first (fetching from System Preferences) is most likely to work.

Comment: Have you tried my solution? If it works, please mark my answer as useful.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think you have downloaded a bunch of images?

There is no visible way to download more than one image in the app interface. 
The Save button saves the chosen image to your desktop, next time you click it the new image replaces the previous one.

Comment: Ok, I've just contacted app support, and they say that too... then, do you know where is the current image in my hard disk?

Comment: Why on Earth would you persist in knowing that if the developers make their best to protect their work?

Comment: The reason is that as a client/user I think "Save" is short for "Save to my hard disk so I can use this file on the future". The developer's and artist's work is safe, I will not distribute those files. I've actually made an Automator script which really *saves* the downloaded image to another folder, so I can switch them when I'm not connected to internet. :)